# ORACLE Database - Why SYS User can drop tables but not columns?

Tags: oracle, plsql, privileges

I am learning PLsql with Oracle 19c. I was wondering - why `sys user` can drop `tables` but not specific `columns` within a table? I found [this workaround](https://dbaclass.com/article/ora-12988-cannot-drop-column-table-owned-sys/), where you create a copy of the table for a specific SCHEMA, drop the column in this newly created table, drop the original table, and finally create another copy of the (copied)-table without SCHEMA/USER ROLE.

Is there another, let's say a smoother way, to accomplish this? Or is there any specific reason Oracle implemented it this way?

Thanks.

```
SQL> SHOW USER;
USER is "SYS"
________________________________________

SQL> ALTER TABLE employees DROP (gender);
ALTER TABLE employees DROP (gender)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12988: cannot drop column from table owned by SYS

_______________________________________

SQL> DROP TABLE employees;
Table dropped.
```

Comment: you should never be touching/adding any objects in SYS other than what patches/upgrades do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To maintain the integrity of the data dictionary, tables in the SYS schema are manipulated only by the database. They should never be modified by any user or database administrator. You must not create any tables in the SYS schema."

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-CF1CD853-AF15-41EC-BC80-61918C73FDB5.htm#ADMQS12003

Comment: Oracle logic.  Funny how inconsistently this is enforced. It's allowed to create tables, drop tables, add columns, but not remove columns?

Comment: I just encountered this problem, what a funny oracle logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in this order:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;
```

If the table has data it doesn't work.